# AssertionError: expected undefined to equal 200

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, chai, mern

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/postp',(req,res)=>{
  res.status(200);
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Connected to PORT : ${PORT}`);
});
module.exports = app;
```

Test case :

```
const chai = require('chai');
const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('../app');
const post = require('../router/post');
const expect = chai.expect;

describe('Blog',function(){

  it('get blogs', function(done){
    const response =  request(app).get('/postp');
    expect(response.status).to.be.equal(200);
    done();
  })
})
```

What's the problem?
please specify, is it because I can't access app or something else.

why it's not running

Answer (score 0):

Try using request from `chai`.

```
const chai = require('chai');
const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('../app');
const post = require('../router/post');
const expect = chai.expect;

describe('Blog',function(){

  it('get blogs', function(done){
    const response =  chai.request(app).get('/postp')
                      .end((err, res) => {
                        res.should.have.status(200);
                       })
    done();
  })
})
```

I suggest you to check [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/test-a-node-restful-api-with-mocha-and-chai) link, it gives more details about assertion lib and chai.